# get attributes from html to controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have this .html

> ```
> <% @resources.each do |resource| %>
>   <tr>
>     <!-- -1 es para mostrar todos los recursos que faltan % -->
>     <% if (resource.curso_id = params[:id] or params[:id] ="-1") and resource.cantidad>0 %>
>         <td><%= resource.title %></td>
>         <td><%= @curso.nombre %></td>
>         <td><%= @user.name %></td>
>         <!-- %= image_tag(resource.imagen_url, :width => 190, :height => 190) if resource.imagen.present? % -->
>         <td><%= resource.cantidad %></td>
>         <td><%= link_to 'Show   ', resource %></td>
> ```

and this controller:

```
def index
  if params[:id] != "-1"
    @resources = Resource.where(:curso_id => params[:id])
    @curso = Curso.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(@curso.user_id)
  else
    @resources = Resource.all
    # HERE IS THE ERROR. I WANT TO GET THE COURSE BUT I WANT THE FIELD CURSO_ID THAT IS IN RESOURCE TABLE
    @cursos = Cursos.find(@resource.curso_id)
    @user = User.find(@curso.user_id)
  end
end
```

the part that is above the if works ok. but the part below doesnt work. i want to get an attribute from resource in html and use in my controller. how could it be possible? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your [model associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) are not set up.

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :curso
end

class Curso < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :resources
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cursos
end
```

After that, you can simply access them in view template:

```
<% @resources.each do |resource| %>
  <% resource.curso %>
  <% resource.curso.user %>
<% end %>
```

Lastly, I'd like to add that using localized names for your model attributes is a real bad practice.

Comment: i want to get the name of the curso but its not working. i made the following: <%= resource.curso.nombre %> and it gives me : undefined method `nombre' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @hernan: If associations are set up correctly, than your `resource` does not have related `curso` record. You can always use <%= resource.curso.try(:nombre) %>. More about `try` here: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/Object/try

Don't forget to mark correct question. :)

Answer (score 0):

`@resource` is not defined. You have defined `@resources = Resource.all`(notice the **s**).
Plus `Resource.all` returns an array or objects of type `Resource`. Please explain what you're trying to achieve.